# EJS page shows as plain text

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I've been trying to deploy my website on a2hosting for a while now, and restarted from scratch, by deleting all former project files, node.js files and npm files from my server.

Here is what I did to set up my website after the restart:

- Made a project in Atom to put up as a test website.
  I used 
  [Keep Getting Error 503 - Node.js app on A2Hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49833548/keep-getting-error-503-node-js-app-on-a2hosting)
  as an example of .htaccess.
- I made a node.js app using the selector in a2hosting, to get the http.createserver() code, using this guide
  https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-software/create-application-with-nodejs-selector
  and deleted the node.js app in the selector after getting the code.
- Installed node.js and npm using 
  https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual- installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts
- Sat the permissions according to:
  https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/403-forbidden-error-message

Now I can go to my website url and it shows me my home.ejs.
The problem is that it is shown as plain text like this:

```
<%- include("partials/header") %>
<h1>Hello world</h1>

<%- include("partials/footer") %>
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
// jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const app = express();

var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {});
server.listen();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.render("home");
});
```

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ views/$home.ejs [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:49555/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:49555/$1 [P,L]
DirectoryIndex views/home.ejs
```

I am not sure what the problem is, I've googled a bit, but haven't found anyone having solved the problem. Can you help?

Comment: You're serving the ejs file directly from Apache and not sending the HTTP request to your Node.js server at all.

Comment: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts#Integrating-a-Node.js-application-with-the-web-server

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. Is there any chance you could link to a guide, that explains how to send a http request to the node.js server? I pretty much copied my .htaccess file from the link you send in the first place.